# HTML5 - Get audio and video started together?

Tags: javascript, html, css, html5-video, html5-audio

How would I go about getting audio and video started exactly at the same time using `<audio>` and `<video>`? JavaScript is fine (and is probably needed).

Thanks!

Comment: why not add the audio to the video?

Comment: In case I want to change the audio.

Comment: Fair point.. I suggest having a look at this http://www.w3schools.com/html5/av_met_play.asp, it looks as though both audio and video elemtns use play(), which you could attach to a button click for example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You didn't say anything about file types so I used HTML-5 formats that work in Safari.

```
<!DOCTYPE>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title> audio video</title>

    <audio id="audioInHTML" controls="controls">     
    <source src="audio.wav" type="audio/wav"/>
    </audio>
    </div>

    <video id="videoInHTML" width="320" height="240" controls="controls">
      <source src="movie.mp4" type="video/mp4" />
    </video>

    <div id="playButtonDiv" </div>

    <form>
    <input type="button" value="PlaySoundAndVideo" onClick="PlaySoundAndVideo('videoInHTML'),PlaySoundAndVideo('audioInHTML')">

    </div>

    <script>

    function PlaySoundAndVideo(soundObj,videoObj) {
    var soundAndVideo=document.getElementById(soundObj,videoObj);
    soundAndVideo.play();
    }


    </script>

    <style type="text/css">


    #playButtonDiv {
    position:absolute;
    top:800px;

    };   

    </style>
```

Comment: I doubt this works, because there is a gap between the play event and the actual start of playing the video/audio. Both will start, but I think they arent synchron.

Comment: They play when the button is pushed. As far as "synchronization" he didn't ask for that. He asked to have the two play at the same time.I posted what I thought would be a bare minimum conventional answer. I'm sure you're probably right but nobody else posted anything and I'm a newbi ...so it was a window opening to actually answer a question. :)

Comment: Your answer is technically correct. But I've seen some benchmarks about playing a video from browser. That benchmark said, that a video-tag may need up to 2 seconds, if the play-button is pressed the first time. The second time, the button is pressed, it is magnitudes faster.