# Video and Webcam playback?

Tags: java, video, media, webcam, playback

My programming experience is somewhat limited in this field, so please don't make things too complicated.

Problem:
The program must first run a video file fullscreen, and after its done I want to show the webcam feed LIVE along with an audio file playing in the background. I thought about doing some simple batch file that uses VLC commands, but I don't know how. I know VLC supports most of which I'm after.

Algorithm:

1. Black screen until user presses a button to start the program.
2. Video file plays in fullscreen until it ends.
3. Webcam streams fullscreen live with an audio file is played in the background.
4. Program restarts when the audio file is finished playing.

@echo
cd c:\program files\videolan\vlc
vlc dshow://
@echo off

Above code will start the webcam streaming in VLC for example. This code could be extended or another one could be written.

Comment: Let your webcam stream to an local adres, and make an website which plays the audio file AND embed the video stream. This is the most simple solution...

Comment: @Mathlight but before that I'd have to somehow show a video. The person watching the screen should first have to see a video to then see the website you are speaking of.

Comment: You could make an simple script that would only play the music if the button has pressed... But this solution is way to 'hackisch'.

Answer (score 0):

Alright, if I understand your question right, you want to create 2 "separate" applications.

The first application will be an program which will let you record the camera feed depending on the state of the buttons. The second application will be an website which will play the recorded video, and an separate audio file.

The first program will have an structure similar to this: (note, this is all pseudo code)

```
if(button.startRecording.isPressed())
    startRecording() & streamToScreen()
    while(button.stopRecording.isPressed() == false) // As long as the stop button isn't pressed
        wait()
    stopRecording() & stopStreamToScreen()

    repeat()
```

The video will be saved to the media folder of your web-app which will look something like this: ( *[credits goes to @William](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10815417/1175881)*

```
<audio id="audioInHTML" controls="controls">
    <source src="audio.wav" type="audio/wav" />
</audio>

<video id="videoInHTML" width="320" height="240" controls="controls">
    <source src="movie.mp4" type="video/mp4" />
</video>

<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        var soundAndVideo=document.getElementById("audioInHTML", "videoInHTML");
        soundAndVideo.play();
    });
</script>
```

You could give the video an unique name (something with date and time) while you save it and give that as an `GET` parameter to the web-app, but that's all up to you.

[HTML5 has an API capable of getting an feed from the webcam. Maybe worth an investigation for your particulair problem?](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/getusermedia/intro/)

Comment: I can see where you're going with this, but I don't think it's quite what I need. All the user input does is start the "experience" after which a local video file is played in fullscreen. When it's done playing, the user sees the webcam feed live (in fullscreen also) whilst an audio file is playing. When that is done, the whole screen goes black, until the user presses something for an input.

I thought about a batch file right now using VLC (I've updated my post above). VLC does have support for webcam streaming, and playing files.