# is it possible to play html5 audio or youtube video play at one current time?

Tags: jquery, html, audio, youtube, popup

is it possible to play html5 audio or youtube video play at one current time?
**i have two sources 1. audio tag 2. YouTube video.**

if i play youtube video then audio format will be mute/pause/stop automatically.
and when i close youtube video then audio will play automatically as a background in my site.

```
<audio autoplay loop id="sound1"><source src="https://raw.githubusercontent.com/shansana/Simple-mouse-move-parallax/master/sounds/background.mp3"></audio>
<a href="#" id="js-video-button-2" data-video-id='EKyirtVHsK0' style="color:red">Popup link </a>


 $(document).ready(function(){
    $("#js-video-button-2").modalVideo();
  });
```

Example : [Example](https://jsfiddle.net/4h8o1mm2/14/)

Comment: did you see this post? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10806338/html5-get-audio-and-video-started-together

Comment: no need for play together. i want play at time one play